# Error while calculating a NDimensional array sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I encounter this error in python

```
import scipy as sc
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy.matrices import Matrix, eye, zeros, ones, diag, GramSchmidt, Trace
from sympy.interactive.printing import init_printing
from sympy import derive_by_array
from sympy import sin, cos 
import math
from scipy import integrate
from sympy.abc import i, j, k, l

theta, phi = symbols('theta, phi')
H=MutableDenseNDimArray([1 for i in range(81)], (3,3,3,3)) 
P=MutableDenseNDimArray([1 for i in range(81)], (3,3,3,3))
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
          for l in range(3): 
              integrand = sp.lambdify([theta, phi], H[i,j,k,l]*sin(phi))
              P[i,j,k,l]=sc.integrate.dblquad (integrand, 0,np.pi,  0, 2*np.pi)
```

When I try to run this function i get the error: raise NotImplementedError
I think this error returns when the code calculates P[i,j,k,l] = sc.integrate.d...

Comment: The code as shown doesn't run because of missing imports and declarations. You should simplify your example so that it is small but complete. You should also include the full traceback.

Comment: I modified my original message and I put a more simplified example which gives me the same error

Comment: okok i got, the fact is that dblquad doesnt give a float but an array